# Why is .val() not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic form where the user provides a name and description:

```
<label>Name</label><br />
<input type="text" name="name[]" maxlength="255" /><br />

<label>Description</label><br />
<textarea name="desc[]"></textarea><br />
```

I am trying to validate the form with Javascript to ensure that if the name is specified, then a description must be entered.

```
$("input[name='name[]']").each(function() {
    var index = $("input[name='name[]']").index(this);
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        alert($("textarea[name='desc[]']").get(index).value);
        alert($("textarea[name='desc[]']").get(index).val());
    }
}
```

The first alert() works as expected however with the second alert I get:
$("textarea[name='desc[]']").get(index).val() is not a function

What is the difference?  Why can't I use the jQuery function?

Comment: Your labels are rather useless as they are right now. Give them proper "for" attributes and associate with corresponding input/textarea elements.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [eq(index)](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/eq#index) instead of [get(index)](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/get#index) and it will return a jQuery object.  The jQuery object will have a val() method that should work as expected for a textarea.

[val() documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val)

> A value is returned for all input
>   elements, including selects and
>   textareas. For multiple selects an
>   array of values is returned.

Example:

```
$("input[name='name[]']").each(function() {
    var index = $("input[name='name[]']").index(this);
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        alert($("textarea[name='desc[]']").eq(index).val());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 17):

Because

```
$("textarea[name='desc[]']").get(index);
```

is DOM object, not jquery. It has not method val. Use

```
$("textarea[name='desc[]']:eq(" + index + ")").val();
```

for textarea value.